# Failing to upload worksheet through Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, io, openpyxl

I am currently attempting to post an excel worksheet through requests using a "no-code" front-end called Abstra. The developers of abstra explained that I should first use a post request to obtain a certain URL, and then use this obtained URL to post the file itself. This results in a success when I run the code, meaning that the front-end is doing its job. But when I open the "final" URL obtained through the second request, I am greeted by an NoSuchKey error stating that "The specified key does not exist." This means that the procedure of uploading is working well, but no file is actually being uploaded.

Next, onto the specifics of the code. I am writing an excel file to memory, then using Openpyxl I am opening the file once again, protecting its structure, saving it to memory once again, and finally uploading it. Clearly, something is going wrong in this process, and I do not know what it is. Without further ado, here is the code.

```
import io
import requests
import openpyxl as opx

def upload(xlsx, name):
    wb = opx.load_workbook(io.BytesIO(xlsx)) 
    virtuality = io.BytesIO()                
    wb.security = WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword = 'project-password', lockStructure = True)
    wb.save(virtuality) 
    name2 = name.replace(' ', '_')
    name2 = name2.replace("'", '_')
    data = {"name": name, 'filepath': "be6b94dd-6e22-4aaa-9b91-95f87bb543e4/"+name2}
    data = json.dumps(data)
    r = requests.post('https://abstra-uploads.herokuapp.com/file/upload', 
                          data = data,
                          headers = {"content-type": "application/json",})

    dictofjson = json.loads(r.text)
    r2 = requests.post(url = dictofjson["putURL"],
                       files = {'file': virtuality})
    
    dictofjson["getURL"]
    return dictofjson["getURL"]
```

`virtuality` is a stream file, it is already open and thus it should not give me any issues. I double-checked this so I am fairly sure that is not the issue. I also tried using both `virtuality` and `virtuality.output()` but the result is the same: it seems that no file is being uploaded. Once again, I do not think this is an issue with the URLs themselves, as they all exist. Rather, the problem is that the final URL, the one that should be returned, is empty. No file has been uploaded there. I am really scratching my head here, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: At a guess, you might need to do `virtuality.seek(0)` to set it to the start of the file.

Comment: @CharlieClark thank you for the input, but that does not seem to solve the issue.